# passing malloc-pointer gives me error

Tags: c++, c, pointers

When I run this code it gives me a segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int **A);

void main()
{   
    int *A = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    A = (int *) malloc(70 * sizeof(int));
    function(&A);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("A is : %d\n", A[i]);
    }
    free(A);

}

void function(int **A){
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        *A[i]=i*2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
*A[i]=i*2;
```

should be

```
(*A)[i]=i*2;
```

because you need to dereference the pointer before applying the array subscript operator(`[]`). In your current code, `[]` has more precedence than the dereference operator(`*`) as per the [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). So you need parenthesis.

---

Other things to note:

- In C, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- Always check the result of `malloc` to see if it was successful

---

It would have been simpler if you pass a pointer to the array,i.e, use

```
function(A);
```

instead of passing the address of `A` and change `function`'s signature to:

```
void function(int *A)
```

and using

```
A[i]=i*2;
```

in the `for` loop in `function`. Since `A` in `function` points to the address of the first element of the array `A` in `main`, any change you make to the memory where `A` in `function` points to, will be reflected in the array `A` in `main`.

Comment: While true, the proper answer would be to have `void function(int *A)`, with a single pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you can see that im fairly new to c and working on pointers right now.